# Django server is still running after CONTROL-C

Tags: python, django

I start Django server with `python manage.py runserver` and then quit with CONTROL-C, but I can still access urls in `ROOT_URLCONF`, why?

Comment: It might be another process that you started elsewhere/ earlier and overlooked. You can always clean up by killing any leftover processes manually and see if that behavior is repeated.

Comment: Sometimes server process is not killed with ctrl+c and you will need to kill it manually. Has happened to me before.

Comment: How to list all of them? I can't see them in top, I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Or how to kill them manually

Comment: Kill them all with pkill -f manage.py

Comment: The [docs for run server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) has a big warning saying "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING". Is this production or development?

Answer (score 5):

Probably you left another process running somewhere else.

Here is how you can list all processes whose command contains `manage.py`:

```
ps ax | grep manage.py
```

Here is how you can kill them:

```
pkill -f manage.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your script, I would have to say that you have blocking calls, such as socket.recv() or os.system(executable) running at the time of the CTRL+C.

Your script is stuck after the CTRL+C because python executes the `KeyboardInterrupt` AFTER the the current command is completed, but before the next one. If there is a blocking function waiting for a response, such as an exit code, packet, or URL, until it times out, you're stuck unless you abort it with task manager or by closing the console.

In the case of threading, it kills all threads after it completes its current command. Again, if you have a blocking call, the thread will not exit until it receives its response.

Comment: So what should I do now? I want to kill all thread and restart my server

Comment: You first need to find any blocking calls. If you find any, put before it `print "Started Blocking Call on Line <line number>"`, and after `print "Finished Blocking Call on Line Number <line number>"`. That should pinpoint what is still running at the CTRL+C. Post an effected code snippet here. If you can't find one, then you either have to abort it, or post your code and see what SO can do.

Comment: ((The edit button poofed!)) Do you have a `break` and `FN` ((function)) key on your((/an accessable)) keyboard?

Answer (score -2):

just type exit(), that is what I did and it worked